# How do I get a slice of a referenced array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, slice

I have a reference to an array `$arr_ref`. I would like to get a reference to an array containing only cells `i..j` in the original array.

Comment: See http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@slice = @{$arr_ref}[$i..$j];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
my $r = [0..9];    
print $_, "\n" for @$r[3..5];
```

If the variable containing the reference is more complex than an ordinary scalar, enclose it in braces. This is needed because dereferencing happens before subscript lookup:

```
my @refs = ( [0..9], [100..109] );
print $_, "\n" for @{ $refs[1] }[4..8];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@rainbow = ("red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "violet", "indigo");
$arr_ref = \@rainbow;
$i = 1;
$j = 3;
@slice = @$arr_ref[$i..$j]; # @slice is now green blue yellow
```